# Suggest an optimal algorithm for the sum of distances of the first match in two seqence

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math

I have two list say L1 and L2, (minimum) sum of the lengths of the two lists.

**For Example:**

89 145 42 20 4 16 37 58 89

20 4 16 37 58 89

**Output : 5**

89 145 42 20 4 16 37 58 89

56 678 123 65467

**Output : 0**

19 82 68 100 1

100 1

**Output : 5**

Thanks,

PS: My language of choice is C and C++ hence the tag.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  Walk us through the examples, telling exactly what you want to find.  For example, what is a "matching element"?  What is the "sum of the position"?

Comment: What is the "first match"?  With lowest index in L1?  Or with lowest sum of indices?

Comment: What's the output if the fiorst match is the first element in both sequences?

Comment: @AraK 145 has index 1 in L1. Arrays are zero based in C.

Comment: @AraK: Define "first match".  If L1 is {A, B, C} and L2 is {C, B, A}, which is the first match?

Comment: Although the question has been modified two or three times it's still cryptic...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a linear time algorithm using a hash table.

To start with hash elements of `L1` (with element being the hash key and index being the value) if it is not already hashed.

Next, foreach element in `L2` see if the element has been hashed, if yes print the sum of the index of the element in `L2` and the hash value ( index of the same element in `L1`) and exit.

If no element of `L2` is found in the hash table, print `0` and exit.

**Algorithm:**

```
foreach ele N in L1 at position pos
  if N not in hash
    hash[N] = pos
  end-if
end-foreach

foreach ele N in L2 at position pos
  if N in hash
    print pos + hash[N]
    exit
  end-if
end-foreach

print 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Add shorter list to hash (dictionary)  key = number,  value = index of first instance in list

Iterate through the other list and for each element try a lookup in the hash. When a match is made, add the indices together (value from hash plus current index in the list)

This runs in O(n)

boost::unordered_map or stdex::hash_map   could be used for the hash

Comment: This costs O(N) space. Can't be sure sure what OP defines as 'optimal'.

Comment: @Philando Gullible - No! a map<> is sorted and will be significantly slower to insert and find than a hash. Only use a map for data that needs to be arranged in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int sum = 0; sum < a.length + b.length - 1; sum++)
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length && i <= sum; i++)
    if(a[i] == b[sum-i])
      return sum;
return -1;
```

This is O(1) in space and worst case O(n^2) in time. And best case O(1) in time! This algorithm is very quick for lists having a match in the first few elements.